# Bypassing Hydra's 4 billion password limit

Tags: brute-force, hydra

I'm trying to get into my friend's email (he is okay with it, we discussed it) and I'm using Hydra, but it has a limit to its bruteforcing that I can't seem to bypass, does anyone know how I can?

Comment: Even if your friends are ok it's the worst thing to do. You will face some issues : - Depends on the email provider but your ip will be probably banned after few retries - If you have no clue for passwords and want to do bruteforce your computer will run for a very very long time (years or decades) It's not a coincidence if developers have added a limit of 4 billion passwords. - Even if you succeed you will face A2F in some cases - You can have a lot of trouble with email providers lawyers

Comment: The amail provider he uses and I use doesnt have any lock out, so I can try as many passwords as needed. Also I know that there arent any special characters like #$@ and that there are only small letters and numbers, I just want to know if theres a way to bypass the limit.

Comment: @throwaway1337420 note that you might violate the email services Terms of Service and get banned

Comment: This can be solved by not creating a password list: https://superuser.com/questions/1340431/cracking-a-8-char-password

Comment: Using that doesnt seem to work for me, it just shows the default --help screen

Comment: Then you made a syntax error